# gatsbyjs function file uploading error 413 entity too large

Tags: javascript, axios

when I'm trying to make the request with a file of more than 30Mb to gatsby js function throw Axios. I get an error 413 entity too large. Can I somehow increase the request size?
I tried add to Axios config this :

```
  maxContentLength: Infinity,
  maxBodyLength: Infinity,
```

but it does not help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The request is larger than the server is willing or able to process.
Compress your file to make it smaller. (ZIP, PDF,...)

Comment: This is not supported yet: https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/functions/middleware-and-helpers/#custom-body-parsing

Comment: @Mace:
axios.create({
  maxContentLength: Infinity,
  maxBodyLength: Infinity,
});

Comment: Compress - is not  my case